# Why doesn't it has 0 as its output when I'm using threading.Lock to lock thread actions?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.8, locks

```py
import threading

COUNTER = 100000

lock = threading.Lock()

def add():
  global x
  with lock:
    for i in range(COUNTER):
      x += 1

def subtract():
  global x
  with lock:
    for i in range(COUNTER):
      x -= 1
x = 0
t0 = threading.Thread(target = add)
t1 = threading.Thread(target = subtract)
t0.start()
t1.start()
print(x)
# The output shall be zero isn't it?
```

I made this code based on a code I saw in a course, that actually hasn't worked as well. When sharing a variable, threads are working pretty wrong with the data

Answer (score 2):

The corrected code is:

```py
import threading

COUNTER = 100000

lock = threading.Lock()


def add():
    global x
    with lock:
        for i in range(COUNTER):
            x += 1


def subtract():
    global x
    with lock:
        for i in range(COUNTER):
            x -= 1


x = 0
t0 = threading.Thread(target=add)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=subtract)
t0.start()
t1.start()
# Added the below lines
t0.join() 
t1.join()
# END
print(x)
```

The reason of your error is your main thread is not waiting for your child threads to finish there processes. That's why you are getting unusual output as you are printing the value of x in between.

Comment: So even when the thread is locked to access the data we still have to join them? I see this works, but where I saw, the guy didn't use the join() method... Anyways, thanks for the solution.

Comment: The lock is basically used to stop a variable from getting accessed from multiple threads at the same time until a thread releases it. The join method is for waiting until the child thread process is finished.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the explanation. I got ya, and I'll get threading behavior with practice. Maybe the version of python influenciated on the results of the guy who I watched so that I didn't get the same result (He was using an older version of it).